# If $\operatorname{trace}(Z)=0$, then there exist $X$, $Y$, $|Y|\not=0$ satisfy $Z=XY-YX$

Tags: matrices, trace

Lemma: if $\operatorname{tr}(Z)=0$,then there exist $X$, $Y$, $|Y|\not=0$ satisfy $Z=XY-YX$.

It's an old problem but I can't prove it.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045360/solving-ab-ba-c

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to see that the vector space of trace zero matrices is equal to the space of commutators $[X,Y]=XY-YX$, using commutators of matrices $E_{ij}$ having entry $1$ at position $(i,j)$ and otherwise only zero entries. We have, for $j\neq k,m$,
\begin{align*}
[E_{jk},E_{kj}] & =E_{jj}-E_{kk},\\
[E_{jm},E_{mk}] & = E_{jk}.
\end{align*}
Here $[X,Y]=XY-YX$ is the commutator. This proof can be found in texts on Lie algebras, showing that $[\mathfrak{sl}(n),\mathfrak{sl}(n)]=\mathfrak{sl}(n)$.

Edit: To show that already every $A\in \mathfrak{sl}(n)$ is a commutator needs a further argument, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769881/is-every-element-of-a-complex-semisimple-lie-algebra-a-commutator).

Comment: +1, but "easily"? could you pleas add few lines to complete the answer? I don't see how to conclude from your observations without other ingredient, maybe I'm missing something and I would like to know a simple proof of this fact.

Comment: @user126154 Think about the basis of the vector space of $n\times n$ matrices with zero trace. You will see they are of the form of the given brackets. If I were you I would have accepted this answer.

Comment: @Math137 I'm not the one who asked, so I cannot accept...

Comment: @user126154 sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

A proof is given in this paper : **On matrices of trace zero** by A. A. Albert and Benjamin Muckenhoupt. [Link to the paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.mmj/1028990168). You could also have a look at this discussion (which is related) : [Solutions to the matrix equation $\mathbf{AB-BA=I}$ over general fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99175/solutions-to-the-matrix-equation-mathbfab-ba-i-over-general-fields).