# Does there exist $n\times n$ matrices such that $BABCB-BCBAB=B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Found this past paper exercise and I can't figure out how to go with it.

Suppose $n \times n$ matrix $B$, non invertible, non zero.

Does there exist $n\times n$ matrices $A,C$ such that:

a) $BABCB - BCBAB = B$

b) $ACB - CAB = B$

My try:

a) $BABCB - BCBAB = B$

$B(ABC-CBA)B=B$

Then, $ABC-CBA$ is the left inverse or right inverse of $B$. But I can not continue from here. Also, tried the trace cycle property, which leads nowhere. The determinant properties give no important results, since $det(B)=0$.

Comment: For $n=1$ there is no such matrix $B$. So we can assume that $n\ge 2$. Did you try $n=2$?

Comment: B is non-invertible right? So does it have a left or right inverse?

Comment: An example for b:
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad C = \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}.
$$

Comment: Forgot to write that n>1

Comment: B cannot have a left or right inverse either as it is square matrix.

Comment: Oh missed that.

Comment: Do you want a pair $(A,C)$ that satisfies both (a) and (b), or two pairs of $(A,C)$, one satisfies (a) and the other (b)?

Comment: Consider them as two different questions. Two pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution only for b), in the case $n \ge 2$, assuming your matrices are defined over the field of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$:

**Lemma 1:** If $T \in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ with $\text{Tr}(T)=0$ and $n \ge 2$ there exist $A,B \in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $T = [A,B] = AB-BA$. 
**Proof:** Induction on $n$. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045360/solving-ab-ba-c) post.

**Lemma 2:** There exists some $M \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $\text{Tr}(M) \neq 0$ and $MB = O_n$. 
**Proof:** This is quite easy to prove. Since $B$ is not invertible, there exists some $x \in \mathcal{M}_{1,n}(\mathbb{C})$ **nonzero**, $x = [x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ such that that $xB = O_{1,n}$. Then we may take $M$ to be the matrix whose lines are all $x$. If $\text{Tr}(M) \neq 0$ we are done. If not, consider $i \in \{1, \ldots, n \}$ such that $x_i \neq 0$ and replace the $i$-th line of $M$ with $2x$.

Now, let us prove b):

Note that $ACB-CAB = B$ is equivalent to $$(AC-CA-I_n)B = O_n$$ Let $M$ be as in Lemma 2 and denote by $\lambda = \text{Tr}(M)$. Take $T = (-n)\cdot \lambda^{-1}M + I_n$. Note that $\text{Tr}(T) = 0$. Therefore, by Lemma 1, there exists some $A,C \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $AC-CA = T$. Now, just notice that
$$(AC-CA-I_n) B= (T-I_n)B = (-n)\lambda^{-1}MB = O_n$$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

(a) Solution may not always exist. Consider, for example, a rank-one matrix $B=uv^T\ne0$. We have
$$
BABCB=u(v^TAu)(v^TCu)v^T=(v^TAu)(v^TCu)B
$$
and by a similar argument, $BCBAB$ is also equal to $(v^TAu)(v^TCu)B$. Therefore $BABCB-BCBAB=0\ne B$.

(b) Solution always exists. Let $B^g$ be a [generalised inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse) of $B$, so that $BB^gB=B$. Let $K=BB^g+X^T(I-BB^g)$ where the matrix $X$ is to be determined. Then
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{tr}(K)
&=\operatorname{tr}(BB^g)+\operatorname{tr}(X^T(I-BB^g))\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(BB^g)+\left\langle\operatorname{vec}(X),\,\operatorname{vec}(I-BB^g)\right\rangle.\\
\end{aligned}
Since $B$ is singular, $I-BB^g\ne0$. Therefore, we can always pick an $X$ such that $\operatorname{tr}(K)=0$. Since every traceless matrix is a commutator, $K$ is equal to $AC-CA$ for some square matrices $A$ and $C$. The result now follows because $KB=B$.