# Is this possible? AB- BA=I

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have just started linear functionals when I faced the following problem:

If $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ complex matrices, show $AB - BA=\Bbb{I}$ is impossible.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hint: $\text{tr}(AB) = \text{tr}(BA)$.

Comment: As others have hinted, the trace of the commutator $AB-BA$ is necessarily zero (unlike $I$).  In fact this is the only restriction on the possibilities for $AB-BA$, as explained in answering this [previous Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045360/solving-ab-ba-c).

Comment: More advanced students can investigate matrices over fields of positive characteristic.

Comment: @GEdgar : can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Qwerty If $n$ is a multiple of the characteristic of $F$, then the $n\times n$ identity matrix over $F$ has trace $n\cdot 1_F = 0$. So in that case, looking at the trace doesn't settle the issue.

Comment: The accepted answer gets contradiction $n=0$.  But what if $n$ is zero in the field?  (For example, $2=0$ in the field with two elements.) Then $n=0$ is not a contradiction.  Is $AB-BA=I$ still impossible?

Comment: @DanielFischer : Therefore I conclude that the $F$ has to be $\Bbb{R}$ in order to looking at only the trace be enough.. Am I right?

Comment: We guess your question is about $\mathbb R$.  That is fine.  More advanced students may return to this question later, when they have dealt with fields of positive characteristic.

Comment: For any field of characteristic $0$ it's sufficient to look at the trace, that could also be e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{C}(X)$.

Comment: See also [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284901/ab-ba-i-having-no-solutions) and [other questions linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/284901).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For a matrix $A=[a_{ij}]$ of size $n\times n$, its trace $Tr(A)$ is defined by
$$ Tr(A)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii} $$ .
You can verify it yourself that $$ Tr(AB)=Tr(BA)$$
and that $$ Tr(A+B)=Tr(A)+Tr(B) $$

Therefore if $AB-BA = \Bbb I$, then we have 
$$n=Tr(\Bbb I)= Tr(AB-BA)= Tr(AB)-Tr(BA) = 0
$$
which is impossible.

Answer (score 6):

Look at the trace of $AB$ and the trace of $BA$

Answer (score 5):

you can see for example that

$$\mathrm{Tr}(AB) - \mathrm{Tr}(BA) =0\neq \mathrm{Tr}(\mathrm{I}_n)=n$$