# matrices in the form $AB-BA$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be $n\times n$ matrix. What are the necessary and sufficient conditions of the existence of representation: $X=AB-BA$
where $A,B$ are some $n\times n$ matrices. This seems difficult. How to start?

Comment: Well $X$ has to have trace zero for starters. Hopefully others can chime in with more conditions.

Comment: I think I could not understand your question

Comment: @CameronWilliams why? where is intuition

Comment: If $X = AB - BA$, then $$\operatorname{tr} X = \operatorname{tr}(AB - BA) = \operatorname{tr}(AB) - \operatorname{tr}(BA) = \operatorname{tr}(AB) - \operatorname{tr}(AB) = 0.$$

Comment: See this answer by Bill:http://math.stackexchange.com/a/99356/274

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez thanks for the link, i deleted my answer