# When identity matrix can be expressible as $AB-BA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is very basic question; but I am actually considering another side which usually not considered.

If $A$ and $B$ are square matrices of size $\ge 2$, say over reals, or complex or rationals, then $AB-BA$ can never be identity; we consider trace of $AB-BA$ and that of identity.

But, now assume that we have a field $F$ of positive characteristic $p$; consider matrices over $F$.

**Q.** When it is possible to express identity matrix $I$ as $AB-BA$ for suitable square matrices $A$ and $B$?

For this, of course, the dimension/size of matrix should be divisible by $p$.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99175/solutions-to-the-matrix-equation-mathbfab-ba-i-over-general-fields) question.

Comment: See especially this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/99180/155629

Comment: @Travis: yes, I just saw (and found much clear answer; upvoted).