# How to prove this property for linear operator $A,B$ : $AB-BA=I\implies A^kB-BA^k=kA^{k-1}\quad k\in \mathbb N$.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, proof-writing, matrix-calculus

$$
AB-BA=I\implies \forall k\in\mathbb Z^{+} \quad A^kB-BA^k=kA^{k-1}
$$

note: $A,B$ are some linear operators over $V$ i.e. a linear mapping from $V$ to $V$ or $A:V\to V$

> thanks @Mvaldi for pointing out that $AB-BA=I$ can't be satisfied for linear operators on finite-dimensional vector spaces.

---

I want to prove it by induction. But got stuck on the first step.

if we have proved that $A^kB-BA^k=kA^{k-1}$, then
$$
A^{k+1}B=A(BA^k+kA^{k-1})=ABA^k+kA^k
$$

and
$$
B^{k+1}A=(A^kB-kA^{k-1})A=A^kBA-kA^k
$$

> thanks @Semiclassical for fixing the equation.

what can I do then.

---

perhaps we need to find some matrix equation that is equivalent to $AB-BA=I$..

Comment: Please write your try?

Comment: @C.F.G sorry but after 2hours working, I haven't made any non-trivial progress.

Comment: It should be $A(B A^k+k A^{k-1})=AB A^k+k A^k$ not $AB^k A+k A^k$. (Also, second statement should be $B A^{k+1}=A^k BA-kA^k$.)

Comment: Hint: $(XY)Z-Z(XY)=X(YZ-ZY)+(XZ-ZX)Y$ for arbitrary operators $X,Y,Z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Multiply $A$ from right  $+$ Multiply $A$ from left.

Answer (score 5):

For a matrix $M$ denote
$$D(M) = M B - B M$$
Let's show that $D$ behaves like a derivation, that is
$$ D(M\cdot  N) = D(M)\cdot N + M \cdot D(N)$$
LHS is $M N B - B M N$, RHS is $(M B- B M)N + M( N B - B N)$, checks OK.

Then let's show that
$$D(A^k) = k A^{k-1}$$ by induction on $k$.  Just check for $k=1$, and then use
$$D(A^{k+1}) = D(A^k \cdot A) = D(A^k) \cdot A + A^k \cdot D(A)$$

Comment: thanks, and it seems that the problem is sort of related to differential operator?

Comment: @hehelego: Commutation relation... You have such an example if $A = \frac{d}{d x}$ and $B$ is "multiplication by $x$".  But they must act on infinite dimensional spaces ( $B$ "increases the degree" );  yes, it is

Answer (score 1):

> thanks @C.F.G for providing hint.

(Induction). Suppose that we have $AB-BA=I$ and $A^kB-BA^k=kA^{k-1}$. Then:

$$
\begin{aligned}
A^k(AB-BA)&=A^{k+1}B-A^kBA=A^k\\
(A^kB-BA^k)A&=A^kBA-BA^{k+1}=kA^k\\
\implies &A^{k+1}B+(-A^kBA+A^kBA)-BA^k=(k+1)A^k
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is **NO** pair of 2 $n \times n$ matrix A,B such that $AB-BA=I_{n}$. To verify it, we can use property of trace. In other words, tr(AB)=tr(BA) for **all** square matrix A,B.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the original problem statement.

Comment: The original problem is  stated as A,B are linear operators over $V$. not matrices

Comment: thanks for pointing out the fact that this can't be true for matrices.

Comment: Maybe you already learned that **all** linear operator can be identified as matrix, so if this contradiction is occured in matrix situation, so does linear operators.

Comment: But not true for linear operators on vector spaces that have infinitely many dimensions.

Comment: For linear operators, the simplest example is just $(D_x x-xD_x )f=f$.

Comment: Uh... For infinite dimension, you cannot get A,B such that AB-BA=I_{n} for such an positive integer n. [Identify to matrix and compare size of AB and BA.]

Comment: @semiclassical What is operator $D_{x}$?

Comment: Differentiation with respect to $x$.

Comment: Is $(D_{x}x-x D_{x})f$ means that $(x f(x))'-x f'(x)$? Ah... taking multiplying x as $T_{1}$ and differentiating as $T_{2}$ **are** operators such that $T_{1}T_{2}-T_{2}T_{1}$ is identity operator defined in polynomial space.

Comment: @Semiclassical So the original problem is handling for **infinite dimensional** situation, right?

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer. In any case the claim is wrong without further qualification. Over a field of finite characteristic $p$ and any positive multiple $n$ of $p$, there *are* matrices $A, B$ such that $AB - BA = I_n$: In this case $\operatorname{tr}(I_n) = 0$, so the nonexistence argument in this answer does not apply. See Henning Makholm's example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/99180/155629 The claim *is* true over fields of characteristic $0$.